# Flutter usb serial with arduino, Not detecting CH340

Tags: flutter, arduino, serial-port, hardware, usbserial

I'm trying this package [usb_serial](https://pub.dev/packages/usb_serial) to communicate with my hardware devices like Arduino, Esp8266, Esp32, FTDI board, etc.,

Right now I'm using a board with a CH340 chip in it. Device details are matching as mentioned in `device_filter.xml`
[image]

In device_filter.xml
[image]

Am I missing somthing here, please help me if you know. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
In the [example code](https://github.com/altera2015/usbserial/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) I commented  `subtitle: Text(device.manufacturerName!),` line.
The reason is I was using an unbranded CH340 chip, which did not have the manufacturer's name on it.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem and commenting out the subtitle line fixed it for me.

P.S. I added a null check instead...

```
subtitle: Text(device.manufacturerName ?? "Unknown Manufacturer"),
```